# Error: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter

hi guys I have an error I don't know how to solve it please reply as fast as u can please+ I'm trying to do the authentication between sign up page and Firebase Auth.
this is the sign up page :

Answer (score 0):

I really don't like the key word "var", because with the null safety you can't know what is that. And your probleme comes here. Instead of "var", use String but not String? because that is what your "var" key word is => String?  And in your " validator: (val)" check if null return a string.

Where is the call of your function?

```
  void input({required Function onSaved}){
    TextFormField(onSaved: (val){
      onSaved.call(val);
    },
      onChanged: (val){
        onSaved.call(val);
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: I really don't understand can you give me more details

Comment: this error appear to me  The password provided is too weak. even though I entered a strong password

Answer (score 0):

insted of  var myemail, mypassword, myconPassword;
try String ? myemail, mypassword, myconpassword and put a ! operator to avoid null errors  at email: myemail!, password: mypassword!

.... still have doubts let me know

Comment: I did as you say and this error appear to me  Null check operator used on a null value

Comment: That's why you must use String and initiated to "". In your "inputFile" methode I don't see the return of a String value in the "onSaved"

Comment: could you please write it as code to I can understand you

Answer (score 0):

You haven't implemented `onSaved` inside `inputFile` function.
I would recommend you use `TextEditingController`s, they will make your task easier.